# C# using a while loop for SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, while-loop, sqldatareader

I am trying to modify data from a data reader using a while loop to display data as rows on a HTML table on a webpage using innerHtml. It works well for the first iteration but it won't iterate over again for the rest of the data.

Have checked that all the data is there on the data reader so seems to be something to do with my while loop code

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
string description = "placeholder";
string desc_mod;

query.InnerHtml += "<table class='list_format'>";

using (SqlDataReader productList = SQLHelper.ExecuteQuery(query1))
    if (productList.HasRows)
    {
        while (productList.Read())
            description = (string)productList["Description"];

        desc_mod = description.Substring(0, 30);
        query.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div><p>" + desc_mod + "</p</div></td></tr>";
    }

query.InnerHtml += "</table>";
```

Comment: So run through it in the debugger, stepping through the while loop and see what's happening. Does `productList.Read()` unexpectedly return `false`? (You might want to add a variable to check this since repeated calls to `Read` change state). What happens to `InnerHtml` in each pass through the loop, etc.

Comment: Put your while body in braces and see if that helps?

Comment: If this is your actual code then your while loop only executes `description = (string)productList["Description"];` line. Wrap loop relevant code in  {}

Comment: It was the while braces missing that was the issue as you all mentioned. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a set of curly braces to delimit your while block, and your using block:

```
    string description = "placeholder";
    string desc_mod;
    query.InnerHtml += "<table class='list_format'>";
    using (SqlDataReader productList = SQLHelper.ExecuteQuery(query1)) {
        if (productList.HasRows){
            {
                while (productList.Read()) {
                    description = (string)productList["Description"];
                    desc_mod = description.Substring(0, 30);
                    query.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div><p>" + desc_mod + "</p</div></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    query.InnerHtml += "</table>";
```

If you omit the braces on a codeblock such as `using`, `while` or `if` etc, the compiler will only treat the line that immediately follows as part of the block.

Comment: I was going to say after my comment that only the "description = (string)productList["Description"];" would fall under your WHILE loop if you don't use braces.

Comment: This makes it a typo question, which means it should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes, but they've also not debugged this (which was what my comment on the question suggested they do). Had they done so, they'd have seen that only the `description = ` line is called repeatedly, at which point that could have made it a somewhat okay question but as it is it's under-researched too.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Also the explanation is only half if not using braces {}.If you are not using braces then first only while condition will be executed till last record then next line will start executing. That means description variable will contain only last value and one and only one row <tr> tag will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some brackets for the while statement

```
string description = "placeholder";
    string desc_mod;
    query.InnerHtml += "<table class='list_format'>";
    using (SqlDataReader productList = SQLHelper.ExecuteQuery(query1))
        if (productList.HasRows){
            {
                while (productList.Read())
                {
                    description = (string)productList["Description"];
                    desc_mod = description.Substring(0, 30);
                query.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div><p>" + desc_mod + "</p</div></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    query.InnerHtml += "</table>";
```

Comment: This makes it a typo question, which means it should be closed, not answered.

Comment: I don't see a Close because of typo flag, but I agree it's not a useful reference for others

Comment: @RichardHubley: Close -> Off Topic -> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or *a simple typographical error*..." (penultimate option)

Comment: @RichardHubley This IS useful to others. Many others can learn the lesson of "never omit the braces", the very same problem that caused, for example, the Apple SSL bug, which had **immense** consequences....... because of a typo.

Answer (score 0):

using `foreach` loop and `DbDataRecord`

```
string description = "placeholder";
string desc_mod;
query.InnerHtml += "<table class='list_format'>";   

using (var r = SQLHelper.ExecuteQuery(query1))
{
    foreach (DbDataRecord s in r)
    {
        description = (string)s["Description"];
        desc_mod = description.Substring(0, 30);
        query.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div><p>" + desc_mod + "</p</div></td></tr>";
    }
}

query.InnerHtml += "</table>";
```